# Boost Condition Variable SIGABRT

Tags: c++, condition-variable

The following is my main program

```
#include<csignal>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

void signalHandler(int signum)
{
  std::cout<<"SigNum"<<signum;

  exit(signum);
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGABRT, signalHandler);
  signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
  signal(SIGSEGV, signalHandler);

  Context context;

  //Mutiple threads set up and working with cclContext member functions
  //and joined to main thread

  raise(SIGINT);
}
```

Context class is defined as follows

```
class Context
{
  private:

    std::queue<Data> _queue;
    mutable boost::mutex _mutex;
    boost::condition_variable _conditionVariable;

  public:
    void push(Data const& data)
    {
      boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_mutex);
      _queue.push(data);
      lock.unlock();
      _conditionVariable.notify_one();
    }

    void wait_and_pop(Data& poppedValue)
    {
      boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_mutex);

      while(_queue.empty())
      {
        _conditionVariable.wait(lock);
      }

      poppedValue = _queue.front();
      _queue.pop();
    }
};
```

When the exit(signum) is called in signalHandler, I get the following error

boost::condition_variable::~condition_variable(): Assertion `!pthread_mutex_destroy(&internal_mutex)' failed
Segmentation Fault

I ran the code in gdb, allowing SIGINT to pass to the program and got the following backtrace(Its not in GDB syntax, so please excuse it)

```
#0  0x00007ffff4958625 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff4959e05 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff495174e in __assert_fail_base () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff4951810 in __assert_fail () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000b61409 in boost::condition_variable::~condition_variable       (this=0x19f62f0,__in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at ...
 /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable_fwd.hpp:52
#5 0x0000000000b9eb3b in UT::CclContext::~CclContext (this=0x19f6220, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at ...
```

Looking at this output, I believe that the condition variable is not being destroyed at the right time. Is the thread it was controlling already destroyed by the time its turn came to be destroyed?

Comment: The code is not compilable.

Comment: Are you joining all threads before raising the sigint signal?

Comment: Yes, they have all been joined to the main thread